# Setting DEFAULT value in Access 2007 mdb

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, ms-access-2007

I'm executing this query in Access 2007 to set DEFAULT value of a field.
My query is:

```
ALTER TABLE parameter
ALTER COLUMN lool1 SET DEFAULT ''
```

After executing it gives an error saying "Syntax error in ALTER TABLE statement" and the DEFAULT work gets highlighted. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try with space

```
ALTER TABLE parameter
ALTER COLUMN lool1 SET DEFAULT ' '

ALTER TABLE parameter
ALTER COLUMN lool1 SET DEFAULT NULL
```

but if you want to null value you don't really need `default` clause

```
ALTER TABLE parameter
ALTER COLUMN lool1 NULL
```

Comment: Do you have the same error?Why do you want to set an empty string ?

Comment: The error is "Syntax error in ALTER TABLE statement". The empty is the demand of the project. And even if try a code like `ALTER TABLE parameter ALTER COLUMN lool1 SET DEFAULT 'NULL'`, even this gives the same error.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. Don't forget can also vote for the answer ;)